# Retrieve CAS ticket after login

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security, single-sign-on, cas

I have a cassified Spring application (with filters and running ok).

This application must query several external services (Bonita, W4, etc) via REST. These other services are cassified too.

OK.

Now, I need to recover CAS TICKET from spring application to generate proxy tickets for these other services but I don't know how can I obtain the ticket. I tried to request ticket for these services using this URL:

```
https://[cas-service]/login?service=[service]&gateway=true
```

This command returns a ticket (via redirection) but the CAS filter for Spring application intercept this redirection and I can't get the parameter returned.

```
http://[service-url]?ticket=ST-....
```

redirected to

```
http://[service-url]
```

How I can retrieve the ticket to validate the current user into another services?

Thank you!!

PD: Sorry for my limited English... :)

Comment: Did you run through the reference which discusses how to do this? static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/cas.html#cas-pt-client Note there is a sample application that demonstrates the use of proxy tickets included in the samples https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-security/tree/master/samples/cas/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SecurityContext ctx=SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
CasAuthenticationToken casToken=(CasAuthenticationToken) ctx.getAuthentication();
Assertion assertion=casToken.getAssertion();
user_fullName=(String) assertion.getAttributes().get("FullName");
```

From the Security Context you can fetch the authenticated CAS token object. Which has SAML response. CAS token object has details of SAML response. You can query CAS token object to get ASSERTION and you can use it in your App.

Comment: I'm working with .net CAS and need to do the same thing that you're showing above but I'm not sure where these classes are located.  What referenced dlls are you using, and what namespaces?  While I'm not sure if this is correct, I did find SecurityContext within System.Security.SecurityContext.  I'm not sure about the others.  Any help here is appreciated!